# Deploying from Azure ARM templates, Circular dependency detected on resource

Tags: azure, group-by, resources, iaas

New to Azure and I'm receiving the following error when trying to deploy a resource group from an existing resource group using ARM template:

```
Deployment template validation failed: 'Circular dependency detected on resource: '/subscriptions/000000-000-000-000-00000000000/resourceGroups/PROJRAG_Test/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/PROJRAGTestServ01'. Please see https://aka.ms/arm-template/#resources for usage details.'. (Code: InvalidTemplate)
```

Cant see any explicit dependencies that I've defined, I've not used the DependsOn option anywhere, but obviously there are implicit dependencies i.e. my vm needs a disk etc.

And here is the template:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentParameters.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "parameters": {
    "extensions_IaaSDiagnostics_xmlCfg": {
      "value": "projragtestdiag01"
    },
    "extensions_IaaSDiagnostics_storageAccountName": {
      "value": "projragtestdiag01"
    },
    "extensions_IaaSDiagnostics_storageAccountKey": {
      "value": "projragtestdiag01"
    },
    "extensions_IaaSDiagnostics_storageAccountEndPoint": {
      "value": "projragtestdiag01"
    },
    "extensions_IaaSDiagnostics_xmlCfg_1": {
      "value": "projragtestdiag01"
    },
    "extensions_IaaSDiagnostics_storageAccountName_1": {
      "value": "projragtestdiag01"
    },
    "extensions_IaaSDiagnostics_storageAccountKey_1": {
      "value": "projragtestdiag01"
    },
    "extensions_IaaSDiagnostics_storageAccountEndPoint_1": {
      "value": "projragtestdiag01"
    },
    "virtualMachines_PROJRAGDevWeb01_name": {
      "value": "PROJRAGTestWeb01"
    },
    "virtualMachines_PROJRAGDevWeb02_name": {
      "value": "PROJRAGTestWeb02"
    },
    "virtualMachines_PROJRAGDevServ01_name": {
      "value": "PROJRAGTestServ01"
    },
    "virtualMachines_PROJRAGDevServ02_name": {
      "value": "PROJRAGTestServ02"
    },
    "virtualNetworks_PROJRAG_Dev_VNet_name": {
      "value": "PROJRAG_Test_VNet"
    },
    "storageAccounts_projragdevdiag01_name": {
      "value": "projragtestdiag01"
    },
    "networkInterfaces_projragdevweb01240_name": {
      "value": "projragtestweb01240"
    },
    "networkInterfaces_projragdevweb02245_name": {
      "value": "projragtestweb02245"
    },
    "networkInterfaces_projragdevserv01896_name": {
      "value": "projragtestserv01896"
    },
    "networkInterfaces_projragdevserv02149_name": {
      "value": "projragtestserv02149"
    },
    "availabilitySets_PROJRAG_Dev_AvailabilitySet_name": {
      "value": "PROJRAG_Test_AvailabilitySet"
    },
    "networkSecurityGroups_PROJRAG_Dev_NSG_External_name": {
      "value": "PROJRAG_Test_NSG_External"
    },
    "networkSecurityGroups_PROJRAG_Dev_NSG_Internal_name": {
      "value": "PROJRAG_Test_NSG_Internal"
    },
    "loadBalancers_PROJRAG_Dev_LoadBalancer_External_name": {
      "value": "PROJRAG_Test_LoadBalancer_External"
    },
    "extensions_IaaSDiagnostics_name": {
      "value": "IaaSDiagnostics"
    },
    "extensions_IaaSDiagnostics_name_1": {
      "value": "IaaSDiagnostics"
    },
    "publicIPAddresses_PROJRAG_Dev_LoadBalancer_External_IPAddress_name": {
      "value": "PROJRAG_Test_LoadBalancer_External_IPAddress"
    },
    "securityRules_Test_name": {
      "value": "Test"
    },
    "subnets_PROJRAG_Dev_SNet_External_name": {
      "value": "PROJRAG_Test_SNet_External"
    },
    "subnets_PROJRAG_Dev_SNet_Internal_name": {
      "value": "PROJRAG_Test_SNet_Internal"
    },
    "securityRules_http_name": {
      "value": "http"
    },
    "securityRules_Https_name": {
      "value": "Https"
    },
    "securityRules_DenyVnetInBound_name": {
      "value": "DenyVnetInBound"
    },
    "inboundNatRules_Temp_Test_In_Web01_name": {
      "value": "Temp_Test_In_Web01"
    },
    "inboundNatRules_Temp_Test_In_Web02_name": {
      "value": "Temp_Test_In_Web02"
    },
    "securityRules_HttpsFromSNetExternal_name": {
      "value": "HttpsFromSNetExternal"
    },
    "virtualMachines_PROJRAGDevServ01_id": {
      "value": "/subscriptions/000000-000-000-000-00000000000/resourceGroups/PROJRAG_Test/providers/Microsoft.Compute/disks/PROJRAGTestServ01_OsDisk_1_34536a53e9f34af7bc74a7a258d49eb7"
    },
    "virtualMachines_PROJRAGDevServ02_id": {
      "value": "/subscriptions/000000-000-000-000-00000000000/resourceGroups/PROJRAG_Test/providers/Microsoft.Compute/disks/PROJRAGTestServ02_OsDisk_1_1370a985f0ff455387754518c9e2d1ec"
    },
    "virtualMachines_PROJRAGDevWeb01_id": {
      "value": "/subscriptions/000000-000-000-000-00000000000/resourceGroups/PROJRAG_Test/providers/Microsoft.Compute/disks/PROJRAGTestWeb01_OsDisk_1_ec3c4200566741caa971c900aa66de73"
    },
    "virtualMachines_PROJRAGDevWeb02_id": {
      "value": "/subscriptions/000000-000-000-000-00000000000/resourceGroups/PROJRAG_Test/providers/Microsoft.Compute/disks/PROJRAGTestWeb02_OsDisk_1_83b01e93c0ae415e90759a84e4f8e32c"
    },
    "loadBalancers_PROJRAG_Dev_LoadBalancer_External_id": {
      "value": "/subscriptions/000000-000-000-000-00000000000/resourceGroups/PROJRAG_Test/providers/Microsoft.Network/loadBalancers/PROJRAG_Test_LoadBalancer_External/frontendIPConfigurations/LoadBalancerFrontEnd"
    },
    "loadBalancers_PROJRAG_Dev_LoadBalancer_External_id_1": {
      "value": "/subscriptions/000000-000-000-000-00000000000/resourceGroups/PROJRAG_Test/providers/Microsoft.Network/loadBalancers/PROJRAG_Test_LoadBalancer_External/frontendIPConfigurations/LoadBalancerFrontEnd"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: The last lines are dependent on the disks and load balancers. Ths is the whole template?

Comment: Yes, I believe so.

Comment: You can try to remove the last lines which seem dependent.